# How to find is web server running on specific port in Java Script or Jython?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jython, jython-2.5, jython-2.7

My url is localhost:8080, I need to find that server is running or not using Java Script or Jython. I had searched but not found any where and I know the solution in Java but I want in java script only.

My English is bad, sorry for that.

Comment: I'm confused. Are you looking for a way to tell if a server is running using javascript, or to see what port it's running on?

Comment: why not simply send ajax request on localhost and conclude from the response

Comment: first one, i.e way to tell if a server is running using javascript

Comment: Is this from server-side or client-side?

Comment: @prasun how to know the connection is refused? and I shouldn't consider any exception or url not found as a server not running.

Comment: have you tried location.port ?

Comment: @MinusFour I will run that Java script from browser

Comment: Unless your server enables CORS headers it'd be kind of pointless to do this type of check from a browser as you'd need to run the XHR from the same origin (which means loading a response from the server first).

Comment: Add jquery and do `$.get('localhost:8080', function() { alert('Running!'); }).fail(function() { alert('Not running!'); });`

Comment: i agree with @MinusFour